# VS 2012 / Powershell freezing while getting a Windows store developer license

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store

I just installed Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012. Now I want to create a Windows store app.

But every time I try to get the developer license everything freezes...

Example PowerShell:

1. Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration
2. Dialog "Accept"
3. Login
4. Dialog "getting license" (I use the german version, so the message could be different)
5. The dialog closes, the PowerShell Console is still frozen

The same thing happens in Visual Studio (background process not responding). Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a few hours but the only solution I found was to remove Visual Studio and reinstall it completely...